# In C++, how does appending an integer to a string without using the to_string function work?

Tags: c++, string, tostring, string-concatenation

I have appended a integer to string one using to_string function and it works as expected but same task done without using to_string function and answer was different from last case, logically it seems to correct but how does it is actually working I am not able to get it?

Specifically how appending integer to string works without using to_string() function, below in line 1?

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {13, 13};
    string str1, str1Image;
    string str2, str2Image;
    str1 = str2 = "";

    str1 += a[0];  //---------1
    str1 += a[1];

    str1Image = str1;
    reverse(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    if(str1 == str1Image)
        cout << "Both str1 and str1Image are same" << endl; 
    else
        cout << "Not same" << endl;

    str2 += to_string(a[0]);
    str2 += to_string(a[1]);

    str2Image = str2;
    reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end());
    if(str2 == str2Image)
        cout << "Both str2 and str2Image are same" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not same" << endl; // here str2 = 3131, str2Image = 1313

}
```

Comment: In the expression `str1 += a[0]` the program will treat `a[0]` as a single character, with the encoded value `13`, which is the carriage-return character `'\r'` in ASCII.

Comment: If `a[0]`  is `-13` then which character it corresponds in ASCII table

Comment: @pawan097 - You will get a `char(-13)`, whatever that is. :-)  A `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on your system, so the result would vary.

Comment: Unknown, but probably `243` (`256 - 13`). Which is not a 7-bit ASCII character, but depends on your system and settings.

Comment: `#include <format>` and `str2 += std::format("{}{}", a[0], a[1]);`, q.v. [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).

Comment: When you use `to_string` you are not appending an integer to a string. You're **converting** the integer to **text** and appending the text.

Answer (score 1):

`str1 += 13` appends the character with value `13` to the string. That character twice is the same forwards and backwards. On many systems, `13` is a Carriage Return character.

`str2 += std::to_string(13);` appends the text `"13"` to the string. That text twice is not the same forwards and backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s{"hello"};
    int i{10};
    ss << s << i;
    std::string si{ss.str()};
    std::cout << si << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) of `std::string` appends a character to the string when an integer is given.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {72, 105};
    std::string str1 = "";

    str1 += a[0];
    str1 += a[1];

    for (const char& c : str1) {
        std::cout << (int)c << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << str1 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
72
105
Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

These statements

```
str1 += a[0];  //---------1
str1 += a[1];
```

append two characters with the internal code representation 13.
If you will output the result string when you will not see the number 13 in the string.

It is not the same if to write

```
str1 += std::to_string( a[0] );  //---------1
str1 += std::to_string( a[1] );
```

or

```
str1 += "13";  //---------1
str1 += "13";
```

This code snippet

```
str1 += a[0];  //---------1
str1 += a[1];

str1Image = str1;
reverse(str1.begin(), str1.end());
if(str1 == str1Image)
    cout << "Both str1 and str1Image are same" << endl; 
else
    cout << "Not same" << endl;
```

works outputting

```
Both str1 and str1Image are same
```

because it is unimportant what character is stored in the strings.

The code `13` denotes to the carriage return character.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad @Caleth for clearing my doubt one more thing I need to add is that last 8 bits of integers are added to the string example `str1 += 2`, `str2 += 514`, then `str1 == str2` will be true because last 8 bits are same for both numbers, and if integer added is more than `127` then it will correspond to extended ASCII value. This I figured out doing some experiment with the code.

Comment: @pawan097 For starters the type char can behave either as signed char or unsigned char depending on compiler options. If sytr1 contains only one char as for example 2 then str1 will be equal to str1Image. But if you will add different  values like str1 += 2; str1 +=3; then str1 will not be equal to str1Image though 1 and 2 are not have graphical representations as for example characters '1' and '2'.